# Delete Same In Sorted List

Tags: java, list

I'm writing a method in java to delete same char(keep only one from same) in a list.

This is the method:

```
    public void deleteSameInSortedList(){
    CharNode p=head.getNext();
    CharNode temp=p;
    for(p = head; p != null; p = p.getNext()){
        temp=p;
        while(p.getNext()!=null&& p.getLetter()==p.getNext().getLetter()){          
            System.out.println(p.getLetter());
            p=p.getNext();
        }
```

////I think this is causing a infinite loop.

```
        temp.setNext(p);
    }
}
```

But this is how to make the node to print to the next node that's not the same.
Do I hava a miss undurstanding with my code?
What can I do to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite loop happened because when the code got to a node that dos not have the same letter then the node after, he couldn't set the node to point to him self.

That's why I created flag(boolean) that will keep track to see when do we need to set a node.

```
public void deleteSameInSortedList(){
    CharNode p=head.getNext();
    CharNode temp=p;
    boolean flag=false;
    for(p = head; p != null; p = p.getNext()){
        flag=false;
        temp=p;
        while(p.getNext()!=null&& p.getLetter()==p.getNext().getLetter()){      
            flag=true;
            p = p.getNext(); 
        }
        if(flag){
            temp.setNext(p.getNext());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should write down in pseudo code or human readable language what you want to achieve and how this could be done. Something like:

```
Iterate over each element
  If the element's value is the same as the next element's value
    If there is an element after the next one
      Set the next element pointer of the current element to the element after the next one
    Else
      Set the next element pointer to null
```

Some more remarks:

- Initialization of p outside of the foor loop seems to be superflous as it is initialized in the for loop
- Initialization of temp outside of the foor loop seems to be superflous as well as it is initialized in the for loop
- Mixing up for and while loops in one peace of code is not easy to read. You should stick with one if possible
- What is the return type of the getLetter method? When it is not a simple type, you should use equals instead of == to check of the values are the same. Otherwise you check if it is the same instance